# Creating python regex for exact match of a string with other condition in multi line content

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, string

I have a multiple lines file content like

```
s1 = """
   Python is a high-level, interpreted,  Good&
   general|purpose| programming| language. 
   Its design philosophy emphasizes code   Better
   readability with the use of significant Best
   indentation| 
   """
```

I want those lines, where pipe(|) is not there but (Good,Better, Best) should be there. (Good,Better,Best) should be the exact word match.

I have tried multiple ways, but failing

1. `?=^(?:(?!.*\|).)*$)(.*\bGood\b.*$|.*\bBetter\b.*$|.*\bBest\b.*$`
   here issue is special chars are not getting avoided
   like Good& is being as part of result.
2. `(?=^(?:(?!.*\|).)*$).*(^|\s)(Good|Better|Best)($|\s).*$`
   In this one pipe is not getting skipped if it is last char and results are coming as a groups not lines.

Please help me what I am missing

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match the lines where there is no pipe char `|` but does contain either one of the words:

```
^[^|\n]*(?<!\S)(?:Good|Better|Best)(?!\S)[^\n|]*$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `[^|\n]*` Optionally match any char except a pipe or newline
- `(?<!\S)(?:Good|Better|Best)(?!\S)` Match any of the words between whitespace boundaries
- `[^|\n]*` Optionally match any char except a pipe or newline
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GLcGcC/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/IUhGgl)

Example code matching the whole lines:

```
import re

s1 = """
   Python| is a high-level|, interpreted,  Good&
   general|purpose| programming| language. 
   Its design philosophy emphasizes code   Better
   readability with the use of significant Best
   indentation| 
   """
pattern = r'^[^|\n]*(?<!\S)(?:Good|Better|Best)(?!\S)[^\n|]*$'

print(re.findall(pattern, s1, re.M))
```

Output

```
['   Its design philosophy emphasizes code   Better', '   readability with the use of significant Best']
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but if you remove pipe from the first line, still we are getting Good& as a result. Which  should not be

Comment: @yaswantsingh What is the exact logic? Should there be at least a single pipe present in the whole line? Or only a pipe at the end if acceptable? Or should one of the words be matched before or after a pipe?

Comment: if the pipe is there complete line should be skipped otherwise match the given word, not return the line

Comment: I have updated the question string, if you run will find three matches, but it should be two.

Comment: @yaswantsingh Like this? https://ideone.com/IUhGgl